# For the Dutch general election, how many candidates can be on a list?

Tags: election, netherlands

According to the [Dutch language Wikipedia](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kieskring#Overzicht_kieskringen), any party list for Dutch general elections can list 30 candidates or twice the number of seats they received at the previous elections, whatever is most.  This corresponds to what I remember from the past, such as the [2006 elections](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweede_Kamerverkiezingen_2006) where the SP went from 9 to 25 seats, close enough to the 30-candidate limit such that there was speculation before the elections on what if they'd gain more than 30 seats.

For [Dutch General election, 2017](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_general_election,_2017), looking at the lists for [kieskring 12 ('s Gravenhage)](https://www.kiesraad.nl/binaries/kiesraad/documenten/rapporten/2017/2/definitieve-kandidatenlijsten-tk-2017/definitieve-kandidatenlijsten-tk2017-kieskring-s-gravenhage/osv3-9_Definitieve+kandidatenlijsten_TK2017_sGravenhage.pdf) (PDF, 169 kB), VVD has 80 candidates (41 seats in 2012), PvdA has 80 candidates (38 seats in 2012), PVV and SP each have 50 candidates (15 seats each in 2012), CDA, D66, Groenlinks all have 50 candidates despite gaining less than 15 seats in 2012.  All except VVD have more than twice the number of candidates than seats gained in 2012, so it appears the unsourced statement on the Dutch language Wikipedia is (now) incorrect:

- PvdA gained 38 seats but has 80 candidates (> 76)
- Multiple parties gained 15 seats or less but have up to 50 candidates

What are the current rules for the number of candidates per list that parties can field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The current law](http://wetten.overheid.nl/BWBR0004627/2016-01-01#AfdelingII_HoofdstukH_ArtikelH6) states (in Dutch)

> Artikel H 6
>
> 1. [..]
> 2. Op dezelfde lijst mogen de namen van ten hoogste vijftig kandidaten worden geplaatst. Op dezelfde lijst van een politieke groepering wier aanduiding was geplaatst boven een kandidatenlijst waaraan bij de laatstgehouden verkiezing van de leden van het desbetreffende vertegenwoordigend orgaan meer dan vijftien zetels zijn toegekend, mag een aantal namen worden geplaatst dat ten hoogste tachtig bedraagt. [..]

English summary: 80 for those that had more than 15 seats in the previous elections, 50 otherwise (new parties and small parties alike).

> According to the Dutch language Wikipedia, [..]

That Wikipedia page is not up to date.

> This corresponds to what I remember from the past, such as the 2006 elections where the SP went from 9 to 25 seats, close enough to the 30-candidate limit such that there was speculation before the elections on what if they'd gain more than 30 seats.

The changes introduced per 01-jan-2010 removed the "at most double" and increased the limit for small parties from 30 to 50. Those changes were introduced in time for the next elections, held on Jun 9th, 2010.

Clearly this was a reaction to the mentioned situation during the 2006 elections.